# Replace VBA driven hyperlinks with Ribbon xml only code Excel 2010 & 2013?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, fluent

I currently have various custom ribbon buttons in a custom tab that launch macros which are all hyperlinks to; other worksheets, work docs, mailto and webpages.
Is there any way to have native ribbon only code as users keep saving the files as xlsx files which dumps the macros?
I am currently building the custom tab and buttons in unofficial customUI tool.
I was hoping to be able to use the xml in this to somehow trigger the hyperlinks.
Or will I have to use visual studios?

Excel 2010 & 2013

Any info gratefully received thanks

Comment: Rename your `xlsm` file into a `zip` file and unzip it, you'll have access to your custom ribbon in XML ;)

Comment: I can access my xml either using the Custom UI Editor for MS Office (i found on Rob De Bruin's site) or re-labelling the .docm file with a .zip suffix.  My problem is then finding a working snippet of xml to trigger the hyperlink within the ribbon customUI14.xml file.

Comment: You will still ultimately need to write VBA code for the events to work if you want to stay in the VBA/Ribbon Editor world.  You could create an add-in (xlam) instead of the normal macro workbook (xlsm) and then add that to the users' normal add-ins.  In that case, the code (and Ribbon) would live outside the documents your users are editing.  Your only problem there is keeping the add-in enabled, but if it is user critical, they would have little reason to disable.  I have done this on a intranet location as a read-only file.  Just hit "No" when adding the add-in on the copy question.

Comment: The bigger question is, why do your users feel the need to save the file as .xlsx? Do you want to stop them from doing that, or enable them to do it?